# I'm having an issue with material recognition. I don't understand what the problem is

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, the material does not match any of the possible ones, even though it should match the material with the name 'green'. And I don't understand what the issue might be

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MaterialTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Material green; 
    public Material red; 
    public Material gelb; 
    public Renderer characterRenderer; 

    void Start()
    {
        characterRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>(); 
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Renderer renderer = other.GetComponent<Renderer>();

        if (renderer != null)
        {
           

            
            if (characterRenderer.material == green)
            {
                Debug.Log("Character has green material and entered the trigger!");
                
            }
            else if (characterRenderer.material == red)
            {
                Debug.Log("Character has red material and entered the trigger!");
                
            }
            else if (characterRenderer.material == gelb)
            {
                Debug.Log("Character has gelb material and entered the trigger!");
                
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Character entered the trigger, but its material does not match any of the defined materials.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Object entered the trigger, but it does not have a Renderer component.");
        }
    }
}
```

[Object with script and its settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcRiv.jpg)
[Our character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vt8b.jpg)
[The logs displayed in the OnTriggerEnter method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vysio.jpg)

Comment: This is likely because you are comparing an instance of the material to the material asset.  You could compare the colors of the materials instead.